# Proving the uniform distribution maximizes the expected value of the product of a random draw of $m$ elements from discrete distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Say I have a discrete probability distribution $p_i$, so $0 \le p_i \le 1$ and $\sum_i{p_i}=1$. We sample $m > 1$ draws $D$ from this distribution proportional to $p_i$ with replacement, and compute $c=\prod_{i \in D}{p_i}$  Is there a particular distribution that maximizes the expected value $E[c]$ of $c$?

I believe the uniform distribution will maximize $E[c]$, which is the case for small values of $m$.  Is there a way to prove this analytically for all $m$?

Comment: Can you state the problem formally, without using "sample", "draws", etc. -- but using such rigorous terms as "independent"? What "draws $D$"? $m$ of them? Does $c$ depend on $m$? If so, how?

Comment: Seems that Craig Schmidt want's to compute $\mathbb{E}c = \mathbb{E} p_1^{X_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k^{X_k}$, where $(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ has multinomial distribution with parameters $m$ and $p_1,\ldots,p_k$.

Comment: The best you can do is: Put all mass into one of the points. Then $c \equiv 1$.

Comment: If all the mass is in one point, then c = 0, because you have the product of 1 and m-1 zeros.

Comment: Sorry if this isn't clear.  You independently draw $m$ times by selecting one of the $i=0,...n$ items.  Then you take the product of the selected $p_i$.

Comment: So $c$ depends on $m$ because it is the product of those $m$ independent samples.

Comment: @CraigSchmidt : Again, what is $D$?

Comment: $D$ is the items $i$ selected in the independent random samples.

Comment: Once again: If you independently draw $m$ times by selecting one of the $i = 0,\ldots,n$ items and let $X_i$ be the random number of drawn items $i$, then $(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$ are multinomial distributed, hence $X_0 + \ldots + X_n = m$, the $X_i$ are not independent and $c = p_0^{X_0} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_n^{X_n}$. Thus if $p_k = 1$, then of course $X_i = 0$ for $i \not= k$, but $c = p_k^{X_k} = 1$. A simple limit argument shows that here you can use $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: "You independently draw  times by selecting one of the =0,... items."  Are you saying that p_i is selected (independently) on each draw with probability = p_i ? (I am having a lot of trouble trying to understand the questions's phrase "proportional to p_i".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the comment of Craig Schmitdt: Independently $m$ times one of the $i=0,\ldots,n$ items are selected. Let $X_i$ be the random number of drawn items $i$, then $(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$ are multinomial distributed, usually called $\cal{M}(m,p_0,\ldots,p_n)$. Since $X_0+…+X_n=m$, the $X_i$ are not independent. Then $c=p_0^{X_0}⋅\ldots⋅p_n^{X_n}$. Note that $p_i = 0$ implies $X_i \equiv 0$ and (simple limit argument) that $i$ then can be ommitted in product. This has the same effect as putting $0^0 = 1$. Of course always $c \leq 1$, $c < 1$ almost surely if at least two of the $p_i > 0$ and $c \equiv 1$ if $p_i = 1$ for one of the $i$. It follows that it is optimal to let $p_i = 1$ for some $i$.

Comment: More interesting is the problem to minimize $\mathbb{E}c$.

Comment: As shown in my answer (https://mathoverflow.net/a/462153/36721), $Ec$ is minimized when the $p_i$'s are the same. To get that, it is more convenient to use different random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$. That $Ec$ is maximized when one of the $p_i$'s is $1$ is also shown in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the maximum part.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$c=\prod_{j=1}^m p_{X_j},$$
where the $X_j$'s are independent random variables with $P(X_j=i)=p_i$ for all $j=1,\dots,m$ and all $i=0,\dots,n$, with $p_0+\cdots+p_n=1$. Here $X_1,\dots,X_m$ are the $m$ independently selected items.

Then
$$Ec=\prod_{j=1}^m Ep_{X_j}=(Ep_{X_1})^m, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
and
$$Ep_{X_1}=\sum_{i=0}^n P(X_1=i)p_i=\sum_{i=0}^n p_i^2. \tag{2}\label{2}$$
So, $Ec$ is minimized when
$p_0=\cdots=p_n=1/(n+1)$, and $Ec$ is maximized when one of the $p_i$'s is $1$.

---

**Details on the last sentence:** By (say) the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality),
$$\frac1{n+1}=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n p_i
\le\Big(\frac1{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n p_i^2\Big)^{1/2},$$
that is,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n p_i^2\ge\frac1{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^n\Big(\frac1{n+1}\Big)^2,$$
with
$$\sum_{i=0}^n p_i^2=\sum_{i=0}^n\Big(\frac1{n+1}\Big)^2$$
if and only if
$$p_0=\cdots=p_n=\frac1{n+1}. \tag{3}\label{3}$$
Thus, in view of \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}, $Ec$ is minimized if and only if \eqref{3} holds.

It follows from \eqref{2} and the inequalities $0\le p_i\le1$ that $Ep_{X_1}\le\sum_{i=0}^n p_i=1$, and
$Ep_{X_1}=1$ if and only if one of the $p_i$'s is $1$. So, by \eqref{1}, $Ec\le1$, and $Ec=1$ if and only if one of the $p_i$'s is $1$. Thus, $Ec$ is maximized if and only if one of the $p_i$'s is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution that maximizes $E(c)$ also maximizes
$$E(\log c) ~=~m \,E(\log p_i)~=~m\,\sum \limits_{i} p_i\,\log p_i,$$
which is $m$ times  the **negative**  entropy of the distribution. This is **minimal** for equi-distribution.
(Update in bold thanks to  @Iosif Pinelis.)

Comment: This is not correct: $Ec$ is **minimized** when the $p_i$'s are the same.

Comment: True enough, entropy is $-\sum p_i \log p_i$.

Comment: Another question is why this is true.